# Remove a query argument from a URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, uri

I'm trying to write a function that will remove a query argument from a url in javascript.  I think I have it using regex, but I'm not sure if I've missed anything.  Also, I can't shake the feeling that there was probably a better way to do this that didn't involve me messing around with regex half the day and running the risk of later finding out that I didn't take some kind of corner case into account.

```
remove_query_argument = function(url, arg){

    var query_arg_regex;

    // Remove occurences that come after '&' symbols and not the first one after the '?'
    query_arg_regex = new RegExp('&' + arg + '=[^(?:&|$)]*', 'ig');
    url = url.replace(query_arg_regex, '');

    // remove the instance that the argument to remove is the first one
    query_arg_regex = new RegExp('[?]' + arg + '[^(?:&|$)]*(&?)', 'i');
    url = url.replace(query_arg_regex, function (match, capture) {
        if( capture != '&' ){
            return '';
        }else{
            return '?'
        }

    });

    return url;
}
```

Does anyone see any problems with this code or would like to suggest a better implementation or way of going about this?

Thanks!

Comment: this would be better place I think - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of URL-related operations, you better try this awesome js library https://github.com/medialize/URI.js

Comment: Yeah, looks like this would have saved me a ton of time:
http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#search-remove

Answer (score 2):

Given a [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) URL, the following function will remove field-value pairs from its query string:

```
var removeQueryFields = function (url) {
    var fields = [].slice.call(arguments, 1).join('|'),
        parts = url.split( new RegExp('[&?](' + fields + ')=[^&]*') ),
        length = parts.length - 1;
    return parts[0] + '?' + (length ? parts[length].slice(1) : '');
}
```

Some examples:

```
var string = 'http://server/path/program?f1=v1&f2=v2';
removeQueryFields( string, 'f1' );       // 'http://server/path/program?f2=v2'
removeQueryFields( string, 'f2' );       // 'http://server/path/program?f1=v1'
removeQueryFields( string, 'f1', 'f2' ); // 'http://server/path/program'
```

Comment: This will drop any fragment on the URL when the last parameter is removed.

Comment: Because his RegExp is wrong, it wont work when there is an empty value parameter. I used this script and fixed it when realized it did't work: 

new RegExp('[&?](' + fields + ')=.*[^&].*') )